# Counting number of rows with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using sqlite3 on Android. I am trying to find the number of rows which are related to each row in the result. The following reflects the general organization of the tables, but the details are more complex:

dept:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | name            | 
+----+-----------------+
```

employee:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | dept_id         | name            |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

manager:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | dept_id         | name            |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I am trying to query all of the departments, and with each one display the count of the 1) employees and 2) managers. So the result might look something like:

```
id | name | num_employees | num_managers
1  | IBM  | 10000         | 800
2  | FB   | 8000          | 20
```

I would like to do this all in one query so that I can use a single CursorLoader for this. I've tried this, but it's not right:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, COUNT(e.id), COUNT(m.id)
FROM dept d 
INNER JOIN employee e ON d.id = e.dept_id 
INNER JOIN manager m ON d.id = m.dept_id 
GROUP BY d.id;
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In ANSI SQL, you would use COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) but in SQLITE, COUNT DISTINCT is not supported.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks, I forgot to mention it was sqlite in the main text. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joining with both `employee` and `manager` results in *all possible combinations* of employees and managers.
You could use COUNT(DISTINCT) to count only unique occurrences of these:

```
SELECT d.id,
       d.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS num_employees,
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) AS num_managers
FROM dept AS d
JOIN employee AS e ON d.id = e.dept_id
JOIN manager  AS m ON d.id = m.dept_id
GROUP BY dept.id
```

However, generating all these combinations, only to filter them out later, is inefficient.

You could simply compute the counts separately, with [correlated subqueries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM employee
        WHERE dept_id = dept.id
       ) AS num_employees,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM manager
        WHERE dept_id = dept.id
       ) AS num_managers
FROM dept
```

Comment: nice solution with  correlated subqueries

Comment: That certainly seems to work on my example table, thanks! It's funny, I tried something similar to that already, but apparently not exactly the same. Accepted.

Comment: Oh, I was so close ... I was doing in my subquery "WHERE dept_id = ?" which clearly didn't work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
select dept.id, dept.name, e.num_employees , m.num_managers
from dept
left join (select count(*) as num_employees, dept_id from employee group by dept_id) e
on
dept.id = e.dept_id
left join (select count(*) as num_managers, dept_id from manager group by dept_id) m
on
dept.id = m.dept_id
```